# Getting the days between 2 dates in batch

Tags: date, batch-file

I'm making a auto update system, I need the system to open a webpage if the software is not updated for a certain amount of days. I log the date of every auto update so all I need help with is getting the number of days between the last auto update and the current date. I hope you can provide explanation about your code too, your effort is really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using VBS

```
@echo off
set "from=01-01-2001"
set "to=12-19-2011"
echo Wscript.Echo #%to%# - #%from%# >tmp.vbs
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo tmp.vbs') do set "total=%%a"
del tmp.vbs
echo The Total number of days from %from% until %to% is %total%
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this squirreled away:

```
:: Using Powershell
:: Count the number of days from %1 to %2 
:: date format is yyyy/mm/dd

@echo off
set from=2001/01/01
set to=2011/12/19
if not "%~1"=="" set from=%1
if not "%~2"=="" set to=%2
set /a a1=%from:~0,4% + 1
set /a a2=%to:~0,4% - 1
if %from:~0,4% EQU %to:~0,4% (
set "sameyear=(get-date %to%).dayofyear - "
) else (
set "sameyear=(get-date %from:~0,4%/12/31).dayofyear - " 
)

>file.ps1  echo Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
>>file.ps1 echo $a=%sameyear%(get-date %from%).dayofyear

for /L %%a in (%a1%, 1, %a2%) do (
>>file.ps1 echo $a=$a + (get-date %%a/12/31^).dayofyear
)

if NOT %from:~0,4% EQU %to:~0,4% (
>>file.ps1 echo $a=$a + (get-date %to%^).dayofyear
)
>>file.ps1 echo.echo $a

for /f "delims=" %%a in (
'powershell -file file.ps1'
) do set total=%%a
del file.ps1 2>nul
echo The Total number of days from %from% until %to% is %total%
```

Answer (score -1):

You may also want to try something like this.

```
    set/p searchdate= Enter search date (ddmmyyyy):
```

Comment: That answer does not answer the question at all and even the syntax of the single command line is syntactically not 100% correct because of the missing space between the command `set` (argument 0) and its first argument `/p`. The Windows Command Processor corrects that minor syntax error automatically. The space after `=` is instead unnecessary and removed by command `set` on execution.